# Rails ActiveRecord associations caching questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activerecord

in Rails, when having ActiveRecord associations, say:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artists_songs, :class_name => "ArtistSong"
  has_many :artists, :class_name => "Artist", :through => :artists_songs
end
class Artist< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artists_songs, :class_name => "ArtistSong"
  has_many :songs, :class_name => "Song", :through => :artists_songs
end
class ArtistSong < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :song, :class_name => "Song"
  belongs_to :artist, :class_name => "Artist"
end
```

and say that I access a Song like this

```
my_song = Song.joins(:artists).first
```

1. Why is it that when I first access the artist association

   my_song.artists

   a new SQL query is executed, although the list of artists was already loaded by the "joins" command?
2. After the first load of the artists association (so that the cache is built), is there a way to filter the artists **without loading them again**?
   Because

   my_song.artists.where(Id: 55)

   will execute a new query **every time it is executed**, even if there is available cache.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:joins` doesn't load associations at all - that's `:includes` (and its variants `:preload` and `:eager_load`

When you have an association, using relation methods (i.e from the active record query interface: `where`, `includes`, `order`) will always return a new relation (and so will trigger a new query when used). If you want to use the loaded association, use array methods such as `detect`.